# Python Django, есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека для генерации списка пользователей для базы данных ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, генерация-случайных-данных

В общем нужна база данных с пользователями - 300 пользователей - имя фамилия группа. Подскажите если знаете такую. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для случайной генерации можно попробовать модуль [faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker).

```
# pip install Faker
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker('ru_RU')

for _ in range(10):
    print(fake.name())
```

Пример данных:

```
Белозерова Анжелика Георгиевна
Кабанова Агата Захаровна
Калашников Филимон Богданович
Артемьев Архип Игоревич
Лазарева Жанна Натановна
Шилова Ольга Мироновна
Капустин Сократ Всеволодович
Лапин Эммануил Анисимович
Дорофеев Василий Фёдорович
Лебедев Максимильян Владленович
```

---

**PS.** сам `Faker` из коробки не поддерживает возврат учебных групп, но это можно вручную рандомно возвращать, пример:

```
import random

GROUPS = ['АИ-10', 'АФ-0', 'МИ-90', 'АИ-11', 'СВ-21', 'АА-12']

for _ in range(3):
    print(random.choice(GROUPS))
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо